# Create scaled UIImage from UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm trying to generate a scaled version of a UIView on a UIImage.

The code I have so far creates the UIImage and then scales it but I actually need to scale it first and then generate the UIImage for performance.

Here is the code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([aView bounds].size);
[[aView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, aSize.width, aSize.height)];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The idea is to have the first block of code create the Image Context with the scaled size and have `aView` rendered in that same context also scaled.  The second block shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create the Image Context with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, isOpaque, scale);`